# How to pass values from parent.aspx page to user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following setup in my application and I'm having some difficulties passing values my user control.

**ASPX**

```
<% 
       var posts = this.getPosts();

       foreach (var post in posts)
       { %>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%: post.post_id %>" />
<% } %>
```

**CS**

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    public Post[] getPosts(int offset = 0, int lenght = 10)
    {
        var resultSet = db.Posts.OrderBy(x => x.date).Skip(offset).Take(lenght).ToArray();

        return resultSet;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
```

The TextBox value on page load is "<% post.post_id %>". I even tried using the <%# post.post_id %> tag but that gives an error - "The name 'post' does not exist in the current context".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving to a repeater control instead of using in-line C# in your markup code.  Alternatively, you might try using Eval (although, not sure it would apply here):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("post.post_id") %>" />
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. The repeater control is pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The data-binding expression syntax (*`<%# ... %>`*) can only bind to members on the page class. The `post` variable isn't accessible that way.

You *could* add a `currentPost` field to your *.CS* file and then do this:

```
<% 
   var posts = this.getPosts();

   foreach (var post in posts)
   { 
        this.currentPost = post;
        DataBind();
%>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%# currentPost.post_id %>" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My final setup was "<uc1:WebUserControl runat="server" PostID="<%# currentPost.post_id %>" Comment="<%# currentPost %>" />" it worked perfectly for post_id but not for comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried <%= post.post_id %>?

Comment: Thanks for the reply btlog, and yes I tried both <%: %> and <%= %> none of which worked. Well they work just not when placed inside an a asp element, so <input type="text" value="<% post.post_id %>" /> works.